# ActionBar and ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-actionbar

I'm trying to implement a simple app with tabs. I'm using `ViewPager` and `TabLayout`. The problem is that I can't understand why there is no `ActionBar`. Here is my code:

[image]

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    PagerAdapter adapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}
public class MyViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

  public MyViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
      super(fm);
  }
  @Override
  public Fragment getItem(int position) {
      return Fragment.newInstance(position);
  }
  @Override
  public int getCount() {
      return 3;
  }
  @Override
  public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
      return "Page "+position;
  } }
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}}
```

**Fragment:**

```
public class Fragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
int pos;
public Fragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(fragment, container, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
    textView.setText("Page "+pos);
    return view;
}
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    pos = getArguments().getInt("position");
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
 static Fragment newInstance (int pos) {
    Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("position",pos);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
} }
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Also I'm using `AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` theme. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Also i'm using AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar theme

That conflicts with this:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
```

If you want to use `appcompat-v7`, you have to consistently use it, which includes extending from `AppCompatActivity` (which itself extends `FragmentActivity`).

Answer (score 0):

Try extending your `MainActivity` from `AppCompatActivity`

Use:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

Instead of:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
```

**OR,** you can add `Toolbar` to your Layout `XML` as below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```